# How to group data by ranges?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following pandas dataframe (it is just a small extract):

```
GROUP   AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1  AVG_PERCENT_NEGATIVE    AVG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME AVG_TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME
AAAAA   19                  11.000000               25.000000           163.000000
AAAAA   22                  2.000000                146.364198          332.761317
AAAAA   23                  0.500000                44.068225           302.708639
AAAAA   24                  1.000000                122.672215          322.359795
AAAAA   26                  1.000000                143.594896          317.940989
BBBBB   18                  1.000000                121.225692          319.292226
BBBBB   19                  1.000000                40.054707           201.096152
BBBBB   21                  0.333333                29.221458           207.142059
BBBBB   27                  2.000000                103.796290          313.685358
```

I need to make `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1` more continuous, which means that, instead of exact values e.g. `18`, `19`, `20`, etc., I want to put ranges e.g. `18-20`,`21-23`, and so on till around 40.

The data should be grouped by `GROUP` and then `AVG_PERCENT_NEGATIVE`, `AVG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME` and `AVG_TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` should be averaged for each corresponding range.

IMPORTANT: Let's take the range `18-20`. The group `AAA` has corresponding entry with `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1` equal to `19`, while the group `BBBBB` has two entries falling in this range - `18` and `19`. The values of `AVG_PERCENT_NEGATIVE`, `AVG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME` and `AVG_TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME` should be these ones:

```
GROUP   AVG_PERCENT_RANGE   AVG_PERCENT_NEGATIVE    AVG_TOTAL_WAIT_TIME AVG_TOTAL_SERVICE_TIME
AAAAA   18-20               11.00                   25.00               163.000000
BBBBB   18-20               1.00                    80.64               260,19
```

I know how to group data by concrete columns and then calculate 'mean' or 'count' using `agg`. However, in this case I don't know how to create ranges for `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1`. Also, I don't know how to define that lacking entries should not be considered as `0`. For instance, in the above example there is no information about `AAAAA` with `AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1` equal to `18` and `20`, therefore I just want to take the values for `19` *without* averaging with `0` values for `18` and `20`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Steps:**

1) Bin *AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1* into appropriate labels using [`pd.cut()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) by specifying a `bin` sequence.

Specifying `include_lowest=True` would take care of inclusiveness of the left endpoint `"["` whereas `right=False` would make the right endpoint an open interval `")"`.

2) Using the returned categories, re-label them as per desired requirements.

3) Peform `groupby` making *GROUP* and the newly computed binned ranges as the grouped key, aggregate the means of all present columns after dropping *AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1* from them.

---

***binning portion:***

```
step=3
kwargs = dict(include_lowest=True, right=False)
bins = pd.cut(df.AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1, bins=np.arange(18,40+step,step), **kwargs)
labels = [(str(int(cat[1:3])) + "-" + str(int(cat[5:7])-1)) for cat in bins.cat.categories]
bins.cat.categories = labels
```

***assign and `groupby.agg()`:***

```
df = df.assign(AVG_PERCENT_RANGE=bins).drop("AVG_PERCENT_EVAL_1", axis=1)
df.groupby(['GROUP', 'AVG_PERCENT_RANGE'], as_index=False).agg('mean')
```

[image]

Comment: One clarification. I am now trying your solution. What if I want to change the range? Instead of the bin 3 (e.g. 18-20) I want to have the bin 5. I tried to change `step` to 5, but when I change `(str(int(cat[1:3])) + "-" + str(int(cat[5:7])-1)` then it fails saying `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '18, '`. Could you please explain the changing of bins?

Comment: I posted this question as a new thread. If you have time, please take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41968244/how-to-change-bin-size-when-grouping-data-by-ranges